# Display Image from Numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to display an image from my training dataset. I am not sure what the problem is. Each image array has a shape of (200,200,3) and has been normalized. I tried multiplying the array by 255 and using transpose(1,2,0) but the result remains the same.
This is how I processed/normalized the image.

```
img_list = []
for file in sorted(os.listdir(img_folder)):
    img_path = os.path.join(img_folder, file)
    if os.path.isfile(img_path):
        img = np.array(Image.open(img_path))
        img = np.resize(img, (img_height,img_width,3))
        img = img.astype('float32')
        img /= 255
        img_list.append(img)
    img_np = np.array(img_list)
    return img_np
```

To create my dataset I used the following function

```
def data_split(id_arr):
    imgs = []
    labels = []
    for id_ in id_arr:
        for n, (k,v) in enumerate(class_dict.items()):
            if id_ == k:
                imgs.append(img_data[n,:])
                labels.append(v)
                break
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs, labels))
```

I want to display a random image to check if I correctly loaded the images as a Tensorflow dataset. However, I fail to display the original image.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
for img, label in train_ds.take(1):
    img_after = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), 'RGB')
    plt.imshow(img_)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVLeX.jpg)

I tried the code by @LtGenFlower but the result is still not the original image.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ8G0.png)

Comment: Please do not post *pictures* of code. They are neither searchable nor runnable, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using your `img_height` and `img_width` variables to resize the images, you shouldn't be using `np.resize` since it doesn't do any kind of downsampling. Instead, try something like `skimage.transform.resize`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_images
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = load_sample_images()

original_image = dataset.images[1]

img_height = 50
img_width = 75

## Using NumPy's resize
img1 = np.resize(original_image, (img_height,img_width,3)).astype("float32")
img1 /= 255

## Using skimage resize
img2 = resize(original_image, (img_height,img_width,3)).astype("float32")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8,3))
ax[0].imshow(original_image, aspect="auto")
ax[1].imshow(img1, aspect="auto")
ax[2].imshow(img2, aspect="auto")

ax[0].set_title("Original Image")
ax[1].set_title("NumPy Resize")
ax[2].set_title("SKImage Resize")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"I find it a bit difficult to look at the code in these fragmented parts; it would be easier if it were cohesive, but...
img = Image.fromarray(images.numpy(), "RGB") - what is this?
What exactly do you expect to see when trying to display an all normalized images?
What actually are u want to display?
"

```py
img = Image.open(image_path)
img_np = np.array(img)
img_np = img_np.astype("float32")
img_np /= 255
#do some stuff
img_np *= 255

img_np = img_np.astype('uint8')
img_after = Image.fromarray(img_np[:, :, :3], "RGB")
img_after.show()
```

^^^ this should work

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, but I am trying to display the original image after I created my training dataset using Tensorflow. I wanted to check if I had correctly performed the procedure. I edited my post to make the code clearer. Thank you for your help, and I tried the code, but the result is still not original image.

Comment: `img_after = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), 'RGB')`
what it is?
what actual is `img`?

Comment: It should an image of a flower. The image files are from the flower dataset.